# Integer returning methods make components invisible in JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a very weird problem. I am writing an interface for a paint-like program and created a class that extends JLabel. I have added the base components and needed variables as shown below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import shapes.*;

public class denemePanel extends JPanel {

    int radius;
    int height;
    int width;
    String color;
    JButton drawButRect;
    JButton drawButCirc;
    JButton drawButRand;
    JButton paintBut;
    JLabel heightL;
    JLabel widthL;
    JLabel radiusL;
    JLabel colorL;
    JTextField colorF;
    JTextField heightF;
    JTextField widthF;
    JTextField radiusF;
    ShapeContainer shapes;
    boolean drawRect;
    boolean drawCirc;
    boolean drawRand;
    boolean isColor;
    ButtonListener buttonListener;

    public denemePanel( ShapeContainer shapes) {

        height = -1;
        radius = -1;
        width = -1;
        color = "";
        drawRect = false;
        drawCirc = false;
        drawRand = false;
        isColor = false;
        buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
        setLayout( new GridLayout( 0,7, 5, 5));
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 700, 150));
        shapes = this.shapes;
        drawButRect = new JButton( "Draw!");
        drawButCirc = new JButton( "Draw!");
        drawButRand = new JButton( "Draw any!");
        paintBut = new JButton( "Paint!");
        drawButRect.addActionListener( buttonListener);
        drawButCirc.addActionListener( buttonListener);
        drawButRand.addActionListener( buttonListener);
        paintBut.addActionListener( buttonListener);
        heightL = new JLabel( "Height:");
        widthL = new JLabel( "Width:");
        radiusL = new JLabel( "Radius:");
        colorL = new JLabel( "Color:");
        heightF = new JTextField( "0");
        colorF = new JTextField( "yellow/red");
        widthF = new JTextField( "0");
        radiusF = new JTextField( "0");
        add( heightL);
        add( heightF);
        add( radiusL);
        add( radiusF);
        add( new JLabel( ""));
        add( colorL);
        add( colorF);
        add( widthL);
        add( widthF);
        add( new JLabel( ""));
        add( new JLabel( ""));
        add( new JLabel( ""));
        add( new JLabel( ""));
        add( new JLabel( ""));
        add( new JLabel( ""));
        add( drawButRect);
        add( new JLabel( ""));
        add( drawButCirc);
        add( drawButRand);
        add( new JLabel( ""));
        add( paintBut);
        setVisible( true);
    }

    //Methods
    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    //Methods end

    //-------------------------------------ACTION LISTENER-----------------------------------------------
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e) {

            if( e.getSource() == drawButRect) {
                height = Integer.parseInt( heightF.getText());
                width = Integer.parseInt( widthF.getText());
                if( height > 0 && width > 0) {
                drawRect = true;
                drawCirc = false;
                drawRand = false;
                isColor = false;
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a valid input!");
                    drawRect = false;
                    drawCirc = false;
                    drawRand = false;
                    isColor = false;
                }
            }

            else if( e.getSource() == drawButCirc) {
                radius = Integer.parseInt( radiusF.getText());
                if( radius > 0) {
                    drawRect = false;
                    drawCirc = true;
                    drawRand = false;
                    isColor = false;
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a valid input!");
                    drawRect = false;
                    drawCirc = false;
                    drawRand = false;
                    isColor = false;  
                }
            }

            else if( e.getSource() == drawButRand) {
                drawRect = false;
                drawCirc = false;
                drawRand = true;
                isColor = false;
            }

            else if( e.getSource() == paintBut) {
                color = colorF.getText().toLowerCase();
                if( color.equals( "red") || color.equals( "yellow")) {
                    drawRect = false;
                    drawCirc = false;
                    drawRand = false;
                    isColor = true;
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not valid color -just red or yellow!");
                    drawRect = false;
                    drawCirc = false;
                    drawRand = false;
                    isColor = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Before adding the "methods" part, my code was working like this:

[image]

After adding the methods (just methods), it became like this (no components are visible but that is it, they are actually working! So, if I press a button that I know it is there, it works like it supposed to):

[image]

By doing some commenting and uncommenting, I have discovered that String method has nothing to do with it (Uncommenting it doesn't solve the problem and making just that uncommented doesn't cause one.). But the integer returning methods causes this problem both individually and together.

```
//Methods
public int getRadius() {
    return radius;
}
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
//Methods end
```

To solve this, I added setVisible() to Panel but nothing has changed. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: My desired behaviour is the first image, the second isn't. Methods (which are causing this issue) are so irrelevant to this problem that I don't know how to make it shorter -every bit may cause this problem.

Comment: But you are right, I am also adding the methods part seperately.

Comment: @Deligoz check my answer. The reason is obvious. You are overriding the `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` method names because they are already exist in `JPanel` so you are overriding them.

Comment: I am shocked (to my ignorance). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're not "adding" those methods, you're "Over-riding" them - the behavior already exists in the superclass (JPanel). At a glance, it looks like your implementation will return negative numbers, which causes weird behavior; the superclass has its own implementation, which was probably doing some reasonable default behavior.

If you read up on the documentation for JPanel, you can probably find out more about what that behavior was.

Comment: Whoaa. I have changed the width and height to test this. When I made them 10, just a small part of it( "height:" and "width:" strings, from the left) has appeared, but making them 1000 made the whole structure visible. Thank your very much!